# how to maintain the image quality in browser

Tags: html, css

I have designed an arrow shape image(100px*25px) in Photoshop. I am using that image in HTML label background. I have written CSS to change image width dynamically.but its sharpness changing when label width reduces.so how I can maintain the original quality as per width changes.

Comment: I tried but whenever label width increasing,image getting sharper.so how could I solve this problem .

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple versions of your image and use them one by one via media queries.

**Update:**
Here's the example:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
label {
background-image: url(high-quality-img-url.png);
/*other rules go here....... */
}

@media screen and (max-width:786px) {
label {
background-image: url(medium-quality-img-url.png);
/*other rules go here....... */
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
label {
background-image: url(low-quality-img-url.png);
/*other rules go here....... */
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by media queries

Comment: By media queries, I mean: `media screen and (max-width: npx) { div { background: image_version } } `

Comment: Where I have to put this queries ,either in label CSS or different style sheet.please just post any example .

Comment: By using above style,may I get actual result.I mean if I increase label image width the quality remains same or change.because I want to use single arrow shape image to all text labels.

Comment: Edit your image in Photoshop and create lower versions of your image and rename them as described above:

Comment: Lower version means version with lower resolution (less pixels).

Comment: Can I use same image to all text label using less pixels